# Android Notification Builder don't play custom sound

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, push-notification, android-notifications

I post the code that I use to retrieve a message and display a notification from firebase. I receive the notification with the correct text and title, but this notification is silent. Even I set the default sound or the custom sound.
How do I play the correct sound?

public class NotificationMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d("sb.fbv", "NotificationMessaginService.onmessageReceived");
    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String subText = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("subtext");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    nb.setContentTitle(title);
    nb.setSubText(message);
    nb.setContentText(subText);
    nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificavedelago);
    nb.setAutoCancel(true);
    nb.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
    nb.setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000);

    //SOUND DEFAULT
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    nb.setSound(alarmSound);

    //CUSTOM SOUND
    //Uri customSound= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound);
    //nb.setSound(customSound);

    nb.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, nb.build());

}
```

}

Comment: To set the custom notification use:
nb.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

For custom notification I can't help you

Answer (score 0):

To set a custom alarm sound in your notification builder, do this:

```
int soundResId = R.raw.myCustomSoundResource;
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + soundResId);
nb.setSound(soundUri, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
```

using the Resource ID number of a file like `res/raw/myCustomSoundResource.ogg`. It can be in [any of these supported file formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#audio-formats).